# Obtain a ResourceManager for a static lib

Tags: .net, c++, winforms

I have a Managed C++ project that compiles as a lib and is referenced by a windows forms .exe. This lib in turn references a DLL which contains localization code. The constructor of ResourceManager expects an Assembly object representing the parent of the resource. How do I create a new ResourceManager that references resources stored in the lib project?

Answer (score 1):

Hmm which version of VisualStudio are you using? VS2008 (C#) automatically creates a strongly typed wrapper class around any resources that you add to the project (using resgen.exe). Please check if this works for C++/CLI too.